# How to keep track of called methods?

Tags: unit-testing, python-3.x

Is this the correct approach when creating a mock which should track the order in which methods are called for a given class?

```
class MockFoo():

    def __init__(self):
        self.calledMethods = []

    def medthod1(self):
        self.calledMethods.append(self.medthod1.__name__)

    def medthod2(self):
        self.calledMethods.append(self.medthod2.__name__)

self.assertEqual(len(foo.calledMethods),2)
self.assertEqual(foo.calledMethods[0],MockFoo.title.__name__)
```

Can I save something better than `__name__`?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is MockFoo.title?  Based on your example it is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do this, but consider the following two approaches and decide which is the more readable:

```
% cat mockfoo.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest

class MockFoo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.called_methods = []

    def method1(self):
        self.called_methods.append(self.method1.__name__)

    def method2(self):
        self.called_methods.append('method2')


class TestMockFoo(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_list_with_name(self):
        foo = MockFoo()
        foo.method1()
        self.assertEquals(1, len(foo.called_methods))
        self.assertEquals(foo.method1.__name__, foo.called_methods[0])

    def test_list_readable(self):
        foo = MockFoo()
        foo.method2()
        self.assertEquals(1, len(foo.called_methods))
        self.assertEquals('method2', foo.called_methods[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

% ./mockfoo.py
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

["Readability counts."](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Answer (score 2):

Well since method names in Python classes are unique, it's as good a value as any other to use.  Though personally I don't see why you'd bother with self.method1._ *name*_ when 'method1' will give you the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you wanna overengineer it, you certainly can. By for example using a decorator which does the counting:

```
from functools import wraps


class MockFoo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.called_methods = []

    def count_calls(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.called_methods.append(func.__name__)
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    @count_calls
    def method1(self):
        ...

    @count_calls
    def method2(self):
        ...


mock = MockFoo()
mock.method1()
mock.method2()
print(mock.called_methods)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> ['method1', 'method2']
> ```

Or if you *really* want to overengineer it, use a metaclass, which applies the decorator to all methods in the class automatically:

```
from functools import wraps
from types import FunctionType


class CountCalls(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        for key, val in attrs.items():
            if isinstance(val, FunctionType):
                attrs[key] = cls.count_calls(val)
        attrs["called_methods"] = []
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

    def count_calls(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.called_methods.append(func.__name__)
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper


class MockFoo(metaclass=CountCalls):
    def method1(self):
        ...

    def method2(self):
        ...


mock = MockFoo()
mock.method1()
mock.method2()
print(mock.called_methods)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> ['method1', 'method2']
> ```